# how much stuff should be migrated from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I ask a lot of questions about SSRS around these parts, and I also Google a lot of SSRS issues.  Frequently answers will turn up at Stack Overflow, sometimes on questions that are a year or two old.

This might be a silly question, but should I be flagging those for migration?  I know that SSRS is in the scope of dba.se, but I don't want to burden the SO moderators if we don't want to migrate all of the old content here...

Comment: If it's a new question, you should certainly comment on the question and tell the OP they will get great answers here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general rules are:

- If it's highly upvoted (and well answered)
- If it's highly viewed (more than 1000 or so views, at least)
- If it's older than 18 mos

It should stay on Stack Overflow.

Other than that, if it seems to be on topic here, it should be up to the community to VtC to move it here.

We have our reasons on why these rules work, and I'm happy to break it down for you in chat sometime.

Comment: If a post gets migrated, does the user lose the rep on SO?  I would think otherwise a highly upvoted/viewed answer would bring a lot of benefit to dba.se.  I may take you up on your chat offer - but I can't get there from work.  :)

Comment: That's part of it.

Answer (score 6):

1 - It's possible for users to migrate here now.  You can certainly flag them if it's appropriate, but we can vote to close as off-topic and choose DBA as a target site.

2 - If it's an old question, AND it's getting new answers, it's best left alone on SO.

Questions that are good migration potentials:

- Are very in-topic here and closer to the edge there (SSAS, SSRS, database design, etc)
- Are newer (we don't want stuff from months or years ago, especially since it's likely been abandoned by the OP by that time)
- Don't have good answers on the original site

If you're not sure if something needs to get moved, you can always ask in [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) (our chatroom) for guidance.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure I understand your first point - can SO users migrate their own questions now?

Comment: Users have always been able to migrate questions - it's a privilege you get when you can vote to close.  One of the options is "Off topic" and you can select a target site for migration.

Comment: Ahh... I see.  3k rep required.  I'll get there someday.